# Meteor - onRendered is not a function

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have the latest version of Meteor...

```
meteor --version
Meteor 1.1.0.2
```

This is what [the documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Template-onRendered) says...

```
Template.codeSample.onRendered(function () {
  hljs.highlightBlock(this.findAll('pre'));
});
```

This is my js code...

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.virtuebox.onRendered(function () {
    console.log("hi")
  });
}
```

This is my template...

```
<template name="virtuebox">     
      <div class="box">
        <span>{{text}}</span>
        <input type="number" value="0.5" step="0.1" min="0" max="1" name={{text}} />
      </div>
</template>
```

This is the method list...

[image]

This is the error...

```
simple-todos.js:34 Uncaught TypeError: Template.virtuebox.onRendered is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is curious... I'm seriously wondering if you somehow don't have a good blaze on your system.

Really, the new

```
Template.foo(onRendered(function(){}));
```

mechanism makes sense as it provides for multiple callbacks instead of the old

```
Template.foo.rendered = function(){};
```

which only gave you one - but that's not causing your problem.

The absence of some of the visible parts of Template.prototype (namely the onCreated, onRendered, onDestroyed and _getCallbacks functions and the _callbacks object) makes me think that packages/blaze/template.js on your system has somehow been compromised.

You might try seeing if the old Template.foo.rendered works, Though the in-code documentation of the _getCallbacks function states

```
// Fire all callbacks added with the new API (Template.onRendered())
// as well as the old-style callback (e.g. Template.rendered) for
// backwards-compatibility.
```

I don't see how this would be any better; it's not clear what's on your system.

Failing that, I'd try removing meteor from your system and reinstalling it fresh. If its the meteor source on your system that's thwacked, a reinstall should fix it.

Comment: `Template.foo.rendered = function(){}` is working, thanks for the suggestion.  I'm on the latest version of meteor so I'll try to get to get to the bottom of this.